# Unable to manage angular depedencies

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm starting to learn angular but I'm having troubles to manage dependencies and can't see why this isn't working.

My html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="client">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/files/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/files/login/login-directives.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/files/logged/logged-directives.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/files/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="ApplicationController as controller"> 

    <logged-content  ng-show="controller.isLogged"></logged-content>

    <login-content  ng-show="!controller.isLogged"></login-content>

</body>
</html>
```

application.js

(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module('client', ['logged-directives', 'login-directives']);

```
// Controller which contains informations on the session (connected or not, user informations...)
app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope){
        $scope.isLogged = false; // Contains true if the user is Logged into the software
        $scope.currentUser = null;
    });
```

})();

logged-directives :

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('logged-directives', []);

app.directive('loggedContent', function(){
            return{
                restrict : 'E',
                templateUrl : 'logged-content.html',
            }
    });

});
```

login-directives :

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('login-directives', []);

app.directive('loginContent', function(){
            return{
                restrict : 'E',
                templateUrl : "includes/files/login/login-content.html",
                controller: function($scope) {

                  this.validateLogin = function(user) {
                    alert("user:"+ user.login + " pass : "+user.password);
                    isLogged = true;
                    currentUser = user;
                  };

                },
                controllerAs: "review"
            }
    });

})();
```

When i open my html file in chrome i have the following error :

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'logged-directives' is not available!
>   You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
>   second argument.

(I didn't include login-directives because it's the same and it is not required to understand the issue, I have the same problem with login-directives)

Am I missing something ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: there is no module called `loggedDirectives`, you defined it as `logged-directives`.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the line where you've created the directive:

```
app.directive('loggedContent', function(){ // L should be lower case
```

Because, you used **login-content** in html :)

Comment: Thank you, I made the change but I still got the error. (I didn't paste login-content.html and login-directives because the error still appears without these files/directives). Maybe the problem is with the path of my files ?

Comment: NP. It's quite straight forward. Let me know if you still face the error (it's better if you create a fiddle of this).

Comment: That's ok for this error !
I now want to be able to change the " ApplicationController"'isLogged' Value from my form located in login-content.html, I should create a controller to check username/password in my template, connect to my server, OK I can manage it with angular's doc but how can this controller change the "ApplicationController" is logged value ?

Comment: As you don't create a separate scope for loggedContent directive, it will share it's parent's scope. Pls change as follows: app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope){$scope.isLogged = false;}. Now isLogged will be accessible from it's child directive. If you want a variable to be shared across multiple controller then use Factory or Service instead.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my first post with your answer. I've managed to get my login form content (user is an object with a login and a password from the fields of the form), my idea was then to change isLogged to true and wait for my index to refresh itself (nb-show) attribute. Am I missing something ? Do I need to refresh the index or I did it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are struggling with the naming convention 
[Checkout this URL](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide) this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem ... I forgot to add '()' at the end of my directives files.

Thank you for your help.